# Printing a textbot text

Tags: c#, printing, textbox, printdocument

I'm trying to make a program that prints a textbox full text. When I'm generating it to a pdf to see the page before I print it some of the text is missing.

This is my code:

```
private void Print_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PrintDialog PD = new PrintDialog();
    PrintDocument PDoc = new PrintDocument();
    PD.Document = PDoc;

    PDoc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(PDoc_PrintPage);

    DialogResult result = PD.ShowDialog();

    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        PDoc.Print();
    }

}

void PDoc_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics graph = e.Graphics;
    graph.DrawString(textBox1.Text, 
        new Font("Arial", 12), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 10, 10);
}
```

This is the text (Just for a test):

```
hellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohello

hellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohello

hellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohello
```

this is the textbox screenshot:

> [image]

This is what I get:

> [image]

as you can see some of the text is missing. I'm not really familiar with printing so I have no Idea how to solve this problem.

Comment: No, I can't see what's missing because I can't see what should have been printed.

Comment: So you´re missing some hello´s?

Comment: And when you examine `textBox1.Text` in the debugger, it contains what?

Comment: @HimBromBeere yes, the hello is just an example, the problem is in any text.

Comment: In the textbox all the text is presented.

Comment: You probably need to use the override of the `DrawString` method that takes a [bounding rectangle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19sb1bw6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) so it knows when to wrap.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear your problem is that you want the text to wrap when printing.  Have a look at this previous thread: [Automatically Word-Wrapping Text To A Print Page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018135/automatically-word-wrapping-text-to-a-print-page)