# How to detect a string-overflow from a line in C#?

Tags: c#, word-wrap

I wanted to know how to word-wrap in C# when I came across a very good solution to my problem on word-wrapping text in a line [in this URL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5018203/5040900). Unfortunately, I do not have enough reputations to ask the OP directly about **one *specific* problem** I am having(and most likely people dealing with this will be having indefinitely)

**Problem Description:**
I can word-wrap a string if it needs to be word-wrapped with this code:

```
Graphics PAddress = e.Graphics;

SizeF PAddressLength = PAddress.MeasureString("Residential Address: " + RAddressTextBox.Text, new Font(fontface, fontsize, FontStyle.Regular),700);

PAddress.DrawString("Residential Address: "+PAddressLength + RAddressTextBox.Text, new Font(fontface, fontsize, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(new Point(pagemarginX, newline()),PAddressLength),StringFormat.GenericTypographic);
```

However, I could not find the place to receive a trigger whenever the word-length overflows from a single line.

**for example:**
 
In **LINE-2** of that code, whenever the wordlength exceeds **700px**, it moves to the next line. It does that by following the RectangleF to wordwrap. It is doing so ***automatically***, which is a problem since that makes it difficult to know whether it has crossed 700px or not.
This is the format in which information is displayed whenever I tried to print **PAddressLength**:

> {Width=633.1881, Height=47.14897}

I am thinking that If I can extract the value of width from that using PAddressLength.Width ,then I can partially solve this problem. But with that, I will need to calculate if the remaining space(i.e 700px - 633.1881px ) will accommodate the next word or not(if there is one)

**BREAKING DOWN THE PROBLEM:**

- I ***already* know how to word-wrap** when there is a string longer than what  specify by using [Graphics.MeasureString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9bt8ty58.aspx) as given in [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5018203/5040900) in another question.
- But that^ process happens automatically, so I want to know **how to detect if the word-wrap has occured**(and how may lines it has wrapped with each line being 700px width maximum)
- I need to **know the number of lines that have been wrapped** in order to know the number of times to execute **newline()** function that I wrote, which gives appropriate line spacing upon executing each time.

***ADDITIONALLY,*** (*bonus question; may or maynot solve*) Is there some way to extract the value **633.1881** and then calculate whether the next word fits in **( 700 - 633.1881 )px** space or not?

Comment: You can consider comparing the expected height of measuring  a high string like "X|^Â" with the resulting height of the measurment. If it is a multiple you know how many lines did result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an overload to MeasureString that returns the number of lines used in an out parameter: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/957webty%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Excellent! Why did I never notice this??

Comment: Came back to upvote this answer, only to see it already upvoted +1